# How to set command alias for git commit in Windows with parameter?

Tags: windows, git, powershell, cmd, command-line

I would like to be able to type into my cmd or powershell this command and it automatically do a commit with a message like this

```
commit "Finished amazing feature"
```

and it would  execute this

```
git add .; git commit -m "Finished amazing feature"; git push
```

But when I tried to add this alias it is giving me some error and not working, what am I doing wrong?

> doskey commit=git add .; git commit -m "$1"; git push

> error: switch `m' requires a value

Comment: Have you tried without the quotes, so `git -m $1`?

Comment: @aschipfl yes then the error was ````git: 'add.;' is not a git command````

Comment: I would not recommend this as you have no chance to see what you are about to push

Comment: Oh, yes, I missed the wrong command separator `;`, it is `&` in `cmd` and `$T` in `doskey` macros…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell, an [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-5.1) is just another **name** for a command. But you can create your own command, namely a [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-5.1):

```
function commit ($message) {
    git add .
    git commit -m $message
    git push
}
```

Add that function to your PowerShell [$profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-5.1). It will then be automatically loaded into your session when you start PowerShell.

It is called just like you wanted:

```
commit "Finished amazing feature"
```

Comment: Thanks, how would you do the same for cmd?

Comment: Found it ````DOSKEY commit=git add . $T git commit -m $1 $T git push```` In ````cmd ```` the seperator command is ````$T````

Comment: @Liga You can add the cmd version as additional answer to your own question. If someone else needs this. I would never do any new things in cmd though, it's more or less crappy legacy tool every since powershell arrived.